# How to dispose an ArrayList in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, libgdx, dispose

I am developing a game in libgdx that has some enemies that stored in an ArrayList.
Am I need to dipose all of them? and if I need, how can I dispose all of them at once in the dispose method?

My enemies logic is like that:

```
  //This is how i create the enemy (for example, here is the first one)
   enemies = new AutoMovement(new Sprite(textureDontNeeded), "dragon.png",
            (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(0), new Vector2(-90f,
                    -2f), 5, 2);
    enemies.setPosition(10.8f * player.getCollisionLayer().getWidth(),
            2.0f * player.getCollisionLayer().getHeight());
    enemies.setSize(enemies.getWidth() * 14, enemies.getHeight() * 14);

   //This is how I add him to the arrayList
   enemiesArray.add(enemies);
```

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: do you use `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array` ?

Comment: No, I use:
       import java.util.ArrayList; 
        import java.util.Iterator;

Comment: What is the type of Enemy? If it is a plain java object you do not need to dispose it. just clear the array and garbage collector will take care of the rest. But if your enemies are disposable classes or have references to disposables (like Textures) you should iterate the arraylist and dispose them manually. And finally it is always best practice to clear the list.

Comment: I update my question, now there is a code example for my enemy logic. How can I iterate and dispose all the array list? And thank you for replying!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
for (AutoMovement e : enemiesArray)
  e.dispose();
```